# Univalent Function (Geometric Function Theory)

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $n\geq 2$ be a fixed positive integer. How to find that the smallest $a>0$ such that $f(z)=(a+z)^n$ is univalent in the unit disc $\mathbb{D}=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\,|z|<1 \right\}$?

My comment: I suppose that the that question is going to solve by using the Rouche theorem. I try to show it as follows:
\begin{align}
(a+z_1)^n=(a+z_2)^n &\Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}z_1^k=\sum_{r=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}z_{2}^{k}\\
&(z_1-z_2)\left\{ \underbrace{\binom{n}{1}a^{n-1}+\binom{n}{2}a^{n-2}(z_1+z_2)+\dots+\binom{n}{n}(z_{1}^{n-1}+\dots+z_{2}^{n-1})}_{\text{must be}\quad \neq 0 \quad\text{for univalence}}\right\}=0
\end{align}
Rouche theorem tell us that
$$\left| \binom{n}{2}a^{n-2}(z_1+z_2)+\dots+\binom{n}{n}(z_{1}^{n-1}+\dots+z_{2}^{n-1})\right|<\binom{n}{1}a^{n-1}$$ that means that for $z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{D}$
$$ \binom{n}{2}a^{n-2}\left|(z_1+z_2)\right|+\dots+\binom{n}{n}\left|(z_{1}^{n-1}+\dots+z_{2}^{n-1}\right|)<\binom{n}{1}a^{n-1}$$ which is equal to
$$2\binom{n}{2}a^{n-2}+3\binom{n}{3}a^{n-3}\dots+n\binom{n}{n}<\binom{n}{1}a^{n-1}.$$
Unfortunately,I think that something is wrong. I couldn't how to proceed from this point.
As far as I know that the correct answer of question is $a=\csc(\frac{\pi}{n})$
In advance, thank you so much your help.

Answer (score 1):

Let's investigate the equation $(w+a)^n=(a+z)^n, w \ne z$ in the unit disc. So $a+w=e^{2\pi ik/n}(a+z)$ for some $k=1,..n-1$ or $-2i\sin \frac{k\pi}{n}e^{k\pi i/n}a=e^{2\pi ik/n}z-w$

Now clearly if $a \sin \frac{\pi}{n} \ge 1$ one has that LHS is at least $2$ in absolute value since $\sin \frac{k\pi}{n}\ge \sin \frac{\pi}{n}, k=1,..n-1$  while RHS is strictly less than $2$ so there cannot be such $w,z$ and $f$ univalent.

On the other hand if $a\sin \frac{\pi}{n} <1$  one can clearly take $e^{2\pi i/n}z=-w=i\sin \frac{\pi}{n}e^{\pi i/n}a, |w|=|z|<1, w \ne z$ so $f$ is not univalent and we are done!

Comment: That's great solution. Thank you so much...

Comment: happy to be of help